# How to find transformation matrix for a given basis

Tags: matrices

Let $P_n$ be the vector space of all polynomials of degree $n$ or less in the variable $x$. Let $D:P_3→P_2$ be the linear transformation defined by $D(p(x))=p′(x)$. That is, $D$ is the derivative operator. Let
$B=\{2−x−x^2−x^3,2−2x−x^2−x^3,3−2x−x^2−x^3,−1+x+x^3\}$ and 
$C=\{1,x,x^2\}$
be ordered bases for $P_3$ and $P_2$, respectively. Find the matrix $[D]^C_B$ for $D$ relative to the basis $B$ in the domain and $C$ in the codomain.
I obtained $[D]^C_B$= $\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1/2 & -1/2 & 1/2   & -1/2 \\
    \ 
    1/3 & 0 & -1/3   & -1/3 \
\end{bmatrix} $
by figuring out linear combinations to write B as integrals of C. I am stuck because this is not the right way to do it. How would you do this?

Answer (score 1):

To find the matrix representation of linear transformation D, from U to V, in ordered basis T for U and ordered basis S for V,  Apply D to each vector in T, in turn, and write the result as a linear combination of the vectors in V.  The coefficients in that linear combination give a column in the matrix.

Here, the first basis vector for $P_3$ is $2- x- x^2- x^3$.  The derivative of that is $-1- 2x- 3x^2$ so the first column is $\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ -2  \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}$.

The second basis vector for $P_3$ is $2- 2x- x^2- x^3$.  The derivative of that is $-2- 2x- 3x^2$ so the second column is $\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ -2 \\ -3\end{pmatrix}$.

I presume that you mean the third basis vector for $P_3$ is $3- 2x- x^2- x^3$. The derivative of that is $-2- 2x- 3x^2$ so the third column is $\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ -2 \\ -3\end{pmatrix}$.

The fourth basis vector for $P_3$ is $-1+ x+ x^3$.  The derivative of that is $1+ 3x^2$ so the fourth column is $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 3\end{pmatrix}$.

The matrix representation of the derivative operator, in these bases, is $\begin{pmatrix}-1 & -2 & -3 & 1 \\-2 & -2 & -2 & 0 \\ -3 & -3 & -3 & -3 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: -@user247327 I think you made a typo with the final matrix, but method is correct.